# How to map 8 directions to 1D array

Tags: c#, arrays, math

I have 8 cursors for 8 directions on screen.

[image: directions on screen]

I want to put them into array and chose them depending on direction vector. The order does not matter, but I need to assign `i` coordinate in 1D array for every vector seen above. I spend a long time trying to invent the formula for it, but nothing would work.

The values in vector can be `0,1,-1`.

Pseudo code:

```
Cursor getCursor(int x, int y) {
    int i = TheFunctionINeed(x,y);
    return cursors[i];
}
```

**Note:** Because so many guys were confused by what do I want, I used [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26736622/607407) to make following fiddle: [Mapping vectors to array.](http://jsfiddle.net/qx63d03L/1/)

Comment: What does that mean: "I need to assign i coordinate in 1D array for every vector seen above" What will the end-result look like?

Comment: The end result is an integer that will be used as offset in an array 8 places long.

Comment: Sounds like you need an object map more than an array. But I'm not understanding the relation: you pass in [1;0] and what output do you expect? Or may be you pass in something and expect the output to be [1;0]? What does "assign i coordinate in 1D array for every vector" mean?

Comment: Generally, I just want to have the directional cursors in simple 1D array. Since there will always be 8 of them, it's the best solution allowing modular cursor sets. So I need to map the vector combinations to numbers. This is probably more a math question.

Comment: Are you saying that if the cursor is moving towards the top right of the screen, that you want to output [1, -1]?

Comment: Yes, there's maths but that's not the hurdle. Do you want to track the direction the cursor is moving and based on that determine the output [1;-1] if the cursor is moving towards the top right corner?

Comment: I'm tracking the cursor position and change the cursor image according to the vector. Why is it so hard to understand? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it contains 9 elements, I have added (0, 0) for simplicity.

```
a = {(-1, -1),  (-1, 0),  (-1, 1),  (0, -1),  (0, 0),  (0, 1),  (1, -1),  (1, 0),  (1, 1)}


ZeroBasedIndex(x, y) = (x + 1) * 3 + (y + 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: It's doing what I wanted. For every vector it returns one array value.

Comment: i think OP wants to store indexes rather than vectors for directions that are mentioned in the question, so we can get the mapped index for a direction vector (-1,0) => 1 and when gives an index like 5 then the direction vector would be (0, 1) @OutlawLemur

Answer (score 3):

To map (x,y) as 1d array people uses common formula

```
index = x + y * (xmax + 1)
```

Let's try to do same for (x,y,z), taking in account what all values are in range [-1;1] (can have one of tree values: `-1`, `0` or `1`).

First only for (x,y), note, you need offset to avoid negative indexes

```
xy = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * 3
```

Now mapping (xy; z), note that `xymax` value is `8`

```
xyz = xy + (z + 1) * 9
```

Which makes final formula

```
index = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * 3 + (z + 1) * 9.
```

Testing:

```
vector       index
------------------
(-1,-1,-1)   0
(0,0,0)      13
(1,1,1)      27
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I will surely return to it in the future as it's quite general.

Answer (score 2):

I would also add 0,0 to make the calculation easier.

The function you need, let's call it "GetCursorIndex", can work like this:

```
int getCursorIndex(int x, int y)
{
    return (x+1)+(y+1)*3;
}
```

If you have your Cursors sorted, so that the first represents -1, -1 and the last one 1, 1 you can add a the one for -1, 0 or 1, 0 in in the central Position of the Array, twice... or you can create a Cursor for the Position 0,0... maybe it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, in the end, `[0,0]` is actually quite useful to display *No direction* cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,Cursor>`.

```
var cursors = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, Cursor>();
cursors.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(-1,-1), someCursorHere);
// continue filling it in for each vector.

Cursor getCursor(int x, int y) 
{
    Cursor c;
    if(cursors.TryGetValue(new Tuple<int,int>(x,y), out c)
        return c;
    // throw an exception here or return a default value?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a easiest way to map this. Simply define your array like this

```
ax8 = [-1,-1,0,1,1,0,-1,1,-1]
```

Now loop through till 8, it will give all the points

```
for i in range(8):
    print(ax8[i], ax8[i+1])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could arbitrarily start at a spot such as the upper left corner and order them going around clockwise.

So: [-1,-1] = 0, [-1,0] = 1, etc.

Comment: Where is the formula that will map them?

Comment: It could be a select statement or an if statement